# floor plan optimization?

Tags: area

I have sheets of mesh $7.05\text{ m} \times 2.62\text{ m}$.
I have a floor area of $17.5\text{ m} \times 24.5\text{ m}$.

What is the best way to calculate optimal laying/orientation of mesh?

If someone can advise the mathematical theory I can research it myself.

I recall solving problems such as this in university statistics

Comment: What are other parameters of optimization? If we assume that every sheet may be cut any times, then we can just tak $\lceil \frac {N \times M}{a \times b} \rceil$ tiles, place them in any way until its impossible to place the whole sheet without cutting and then cut pieces from sheets according to the uncovered areas length and width. This makes your problem have no sense, so I ask you to clarify what are we need to optimize or what other restrictions do we have?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, if we cut sheets they must be overlapped by .02m. So we want minimal cuts.